# LINQ Query with GroupBy, MAX and Count

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

What could be the LINQ query for this SQL?

```
SELECT PartId, BSId, 
       COUNT(PartId), MAX(EffectiveDateUtc)  
FROM PartCostConfig (NOLOCK)  
GROUP BY PartId, BSId 
HAVING COUNT(PartId) > 1
```

I am actually grouping by two columns and trying to retrieve max EffectiveDateUtc for each part.

This is what I could write. Stuck up on pulling the top record based on the date.
Also not sure, if this is a optimal one.

```
   //Get all the parts which have more than ONE active record with the pat 
   //effective date and for the same BSId
    var filters = (from p in configs
                            ?.GroupBy(w => new
                            {
                                w.PartId,
                                w.BSId
                            })
                            ?.Select(g => new
                            {
                                PartId = g.Key.PartId,
                                BSId = g.Key.BSId,
                                Count = g.Count()
                            })
                            ?.Where(y => y.Count > 1)
                    select p)
                    ?.Distinct()?.ToList();

    var filteredData = (from p in configs
                        join f in filters on p.PartId equals f.PartId
                        select new Config
                        {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            PartId = p.PartId,
                            BSId = p.BSId,
                            //EffectiveDateUtc = MAX(??)
                        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.EffectiveDateUtc).GroupBy(g => new { g.PartId, g.BSId }).ToList();
```

NOTE: I need the top record (based on date) for each part. Was trying to see if I can avoid for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent query would be:

```
var query =
    from p in db.PartCostConfig
    group p by new { p.PartId, p.BSId } into g
    let count = g.Count()
    where count > 1
    select new
    {
        g.Key.PartId,
        g.Key.BSId,
        Count = count,
        EffectiveDate = g.Max(x => x.EffectiveDateUtc),
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
var query=configs.GroupBy(w => new{ w.PartId, w.BSId})
                 .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
                 .Select(g=>new
                           {
                              g.Key.PartId,
                              g.Key.BSId,
                              Count = g.Count(),
                              EffectiveDate = g.Max(x => x.EffectiveDateUtc)
                           });
```